# Trying to clean specflow BDD test error: Test assembly not found. Please build the project to enable the SpecFlow Visual Studio Extension features

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, specflow, browser-automation

I currently training on how to Specflow with C#.  I made a few changes to my test saved them.  I then performed a 'clean' at project level and got the following error message.

[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Test assembly not found. Please build the project to enable the SpecFlow Visual Studio Extension features.  

    0
```

and this

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1100 Error reading content of source file 'C:\Users\myname\source\repos\UdemyTrainingProject\UdemyTrainingProject\obj\Debug\net6.0\UdemyTrainingProject.AssemblyInfo.cs' -- 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\myname\source\repos\UdemyTrainingProject\UdemyTrainingProject\obj\Debug\net6.0\UdemyTrainingProject.AssemblyInfo.cs'.'.   UdemyTrainingProject    C:\Users\myname\source\repos\UdemyTrainingProject\UdemyTrainingProject\obj\Debug\net6.0\UdemyTrainingProject.AssemblyInfo.cs    1   Active
```

Csprog file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" Version="0.27.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="105.0.5195.5200" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" Version="17.17134.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.9.74" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.9.74" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.74" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Features\" />
    <Folder Include="Utilities\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
```

[please watch this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gszust8ysn7ay1i/Cannot%20clean%20test.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio and deleting the `.vs` folder at the root of the solution directory. This feels like a weird error, and usually weird errors like this are fixed by deleting that `.vs` folder.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of your test project's `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the issue.

1. Go to the top menu > select project> Build> build solution
2. the build is successful go to step 3
3. The Go into the search box with the spy glass logo and type 'test explorer'
4. In test explorer you have the choice of 2 ways to run:

   - the small green triangle will run ALL tests
   - the large green triangle will your chosen test only.
5. Select from option 4 and run your test.

Comment: Ok, so basically you just needed to rebuild the project?

Comment: Seems like it. And find an alternative way to run the test using test explorer.

Comment: How were you running the test before?

Comment: I hadn't run them yet. I spoke to a friend and he ran them and that's how we came to the final solution